# iOS - Blur Effect between .dark and .light

Tags: ios, swift3, uiblureffect

I've implemented some blur effect over an image and everything looks good so far but I came across some detail that I wanted to change.

I think that the `UIBlurEffectStyle.dark` it's too dark and the `UIBlurEffectStyle.light` it's too light for my content.

Is there any way of implementing an in-between color gradient?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try to play with the `alpha` property of your `UIVisualEffectView` ? Might do the trick

Comment: well I did but what it most does is removing the blur effect itself and that's not what I'm trying to do. I'm trying to keep the blurriness but make it more light

Comment: I guess there is no easy way to dit. The most easy way is to set a `backgroundColor` to the effectView (`.white` for instance) and play with the `alpha`of the colored background view. Otherwise you will have to implement your own BlurEffect, which is not the most time saver thing to do.

Comment: pfff... yeah! I even thought on adding another view above the blur view itself with white color balanced with the alpha to give the desired effect. Thanks for the tip :)